# How to resolve 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have done all the solution but none of them worked. Whenever I add this library in my project. I face error like

> unable to resolve this library (disable offline work option)).

After disabling it, the error come

> No cached version available in offline mode(Enable offline work option)).

How I resolve it pls help

This is my gradle file(module app)

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amazone_ecommerce"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.stepstone.apprating:app-rating:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my gradle file(root level)

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this as it's stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
}
```

That's a newer version of the lib. I think this should solve your problem.

Best

Comment: Glad I helped :) Don't forget to mark the topic as answered :)